# Why web.xml DD for Springsource Bootstrap uses a DispatcherServlet and struts2 is using a Filter?

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, struts2, requestdispatcher, springsource

I would like to know why the web.xml for Struts2 and Spring MVC are different.

Both frameworks use "front controller" MVC pattern in my understanding, but Struts2 uses a Filter and Spring MVC uses a Direct declaration of a servlet in the web.xml?

Doesn't Struts use servlets as well ? If it does then how is it that that servlet is not declared in the web.xml as it is for Spring ?

Spring MVC:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Struts2:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: If all MVC frameworks did everything exactly the same way, why would we have serveral ones? They just chose a different way of achieving a similar goal.

Comment: though asking the question though I am trying to learn more about both and about the servlet spec altogether, a worthwhile exercise in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't Struts use servlets as well ? If it does then how is it that that servlet is not declared in the web.xml as it is for Spring ?

Struts2 uses :

- **Actions** instead of Servlets (they're ThreadLocal, hence thread-safe and created once per request) as controllers, to handle the presentation layer;
- **Interceptors** to handle ortogonal, [cross-cutting concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28709075/1654265) <sub>(sorry,wait for undeletion)</sub>, such as logging, transaction management, parameters parsing, validation etc...;
- **StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter** to handle the dispatching process.

So even if the usage of Servlet is possible ([through the declaration of an excluded pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28318069/1654265)) in a Struts2 application... **no, Struts2 doesn't use Servlets** at all.

Struts2 also puts values in the ValueStack instead of pushing them in the request, and this makes it the only mainstream [**Pull-MVC** framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441926/push-vs-pull-model-in-mvc) (while Spring MVC, Struts1 and others are **Push-MVC** frameworks)